# Removing Ubuntu from my PC

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

there.
Before a lot of years, my main work in computer was made with Ubuntu because I hase a computer without an official bought Windows version and I was afraid from legal suits not legal work. When I bought a new PC and bought Windows. in spite I worked on Windows for my office, I made a dual entry with a choice to enter with Ubuntu or Windows. When I upgraded the version 20.04 of Ubuntu, suddenly everything started not working. And since the default option was to start with Ubuntu, it was freezing and no one was able to help me. I made the computer turning on with Windows only. But Ubuntu is steel here. I have no way to get on it and to work with the kernel.
I wand to clean the PC the Linux packages at all because I need free space in the Hard Disk. In my computer I see an icon Linux and have no way to open it despite I administrator.
How can I cancel the Linux packages working inside the Windows system. I chated a lot with my friend chat gpt bu we don't get the solution.
I don't understand why some highly qualified users treated this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @Nmath. No, the PC works fine because after a few seconds it starts in Windows. I want to free up memory from the small hard disk by cancelling all Linux material.

Comment: @Nmath you said "it should be sufficient to delete the partitions for Ubuntu and remove it from EFI. I understand the words. I will try. But the suggested duplicate ask how to put Windows back on, so I was thinking it's not my problem at all because Windows is already on.

Comment: @Nmath I have no DVD, no USB.

Comment: To remove the question is a mistake. Do you don't understand my request. The case is different. Moreover I am not a professional and maybe I didn't explain sufficiently the question. It's not fair enough to let me down in this way.

Comment: It's possible I am misunderstanding you. But my understanding is that you want to remove Ubuntu completely while keeping Windows installed. Can you let me know if this is an incorrect assumption? To be fair, look at the "editors note" on the question. I understand there's a lot of information on that page which can be overwhelming. You can apply the details of the first answer to the actions I mentioned above. Look for "Deleting Ubuntu Partitions" and "Changing the Boot Sequence". If this isn't enough, describe exactly where you're stuck so we can hopefully help you past that point

Comment: If you want to remove an OS, you don't use that OS to remove it; you remove the OS you want to remain; ie. you're best doing this in Windows given you want to keep that. You can also install another OS (*such as Linux Mint for example*) it can just replace the unwanted OS; however this site supports Ubuntu & your question is related to windows tools to remove the unwanted EFI entries as I understand it. If you have no Ubuntu DVD/USB you'll need to use windows recovery media but that's off-topic here.

Comment: As far as changing boot sequence, an example of a Dell computer is used, which may be different for your computer. Making changes to UEFI settings are different depending on what kind of motherboard you have. So if your system is still trying to boot to Ubuntu, you may need to additionally research the documentation for the UEFI/BIOS of your particular computer. To get a bit more technical, there may be a handful of files remaining on the actual EFI partition, but arguably, that is inconsequential as long as you've removed the actual Ubuntu OS partitions and made Windows 1st boot priority.

Comment: @Nmath my system is still not trying to boot to Ubuntu. I already made Windows as the first choice and reduced at the maximum the time latency for the automatic booting to widows. I need only to get space in my Hard disk because it has not a lot of Gigas. So I want to cancel from the memory all the Linux. I'm not upset, but I'm like a passer-by who asks for directions in the street and is vaguely shown his way by a wave of the hand without stopping.

Comment: @guiverc My first choice is to remove the OS, no more.

Comment: Windows has commands that will ensure that windows controls the boot process (ie. you won't see `grub` which Ubuntu uses as a boot loader by default; commands vary on windows version being used) after which you can just remove the partition(s) that were used by Ubuntu without effect (*that can be done within windows; the key is just to ensure windows controls your machines boot first as any remaining grub pointer will point invalid once the partition on which it was installed is deleted; refer to the commands of your windows version*)

Comment: Let me try to give clearer instruction on how to use this resource with your scenario. Click the [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533). Then type `ALT`+`F` to search the page. Type `Deleting Ubuntu Partitions` in the search box. Complete steps 4, 5, and 6 in Windows Disk Utility to delete the Ubuntu partitions, and expand your Windows partition to the free space. If your system already boots to Windows, then you don't need to do anything else. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Nmath thanks so much. I'm very grateful and if you write it as an answer I'll give for it 25 points.